# Couldn't find [model name] with 'id'= - how to locate an id with a has_many association - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i apologise if this may seem like a simple error, i am new to rails and your advise and help would be much appreciated.

- i have the models `User` and `Advert`
- a user `has_many` adverts
- an advert `belongs_to` a user
- advert is a nested resource under user
- my created `user` has the `id:10` when i check in the terminal
- my created `advert` has the `id:6` when i check in the terminal

in the `user's controller`, i am trying to locate the `id` of an `advert`. I have tried the below:

- `@advert = Advert.find(params[:id])`
- `@advert = Advert.find(params[:advert_id])`
- `@advert = @userr.adverts.find(params[:id])`

but no success. I keep getting the below erros:

```
Couldn't find Advert with 'id'=10 [WHERE "adverts"."userr_id" = ?]
```

and

```
Couldn't find Advert with 'id'=10
```

i see that the code is looking for an advert with an `id:10` when i actually want it to locate the advert with an `id:6`

in my users_controller.rb

```
def dashboard
  if current_user
    if current_user.adverts.present?
      @advert = Advert.find(params[:id])
    end
  else
    redirect_to error_path
  end
end
```

in my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users 
  resources :users do
    resources :adverts 
    member do
      get 'dashboard'
    end
  end
end
```

> for a `has_many` relationship (`user has_many adverts` & `advert belongs_to user`). how do i locate
>   the id of an advert in the user's controller. This has been an issue i
>   have struggled to resolved. your advise would be much appreciated

Comment: i think it's an issue with your routing.  If your dashboard member route is nested under user, then it should produce a route of users/:id/dashboard , and therefore the adverts id wouldn't be available as params.  i would run "rake routes" in your command line to investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where in your controller your getting this error, which actions are causing the issues.  However here is an example of a create method for a bookmark class that belongs to a topic and a topic has many bookmarks.

```
def create
  @topic = Topic.friendly.find(params[:topic_id])
  @bookmark = @topic.bookmarks.build(bookmark_params)
  @bookmark.user_id = current_user.id


  if @bookmark.save
    flash[:notice] = "Bookmark saved."
    redirect_to [@topic, @bookmark]
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving bookmark."
    render :new
  end
 end
```

You can see that I find the Topic associated with the bookmark and then use that topic as I find the bookmark to create the association.  The book mark params is a private method.  Then I assign the current user to the bookmark.

Seeing your full controller for both adverts and users would be helpful